# Gspread hide sheets

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to write a python script - connecting with google sheets (google sheets API  & google drive API) - to generate weekly reports.
I could not find a function to hide "old" sheets (from previous weeks) and leave just the recent one - any ideas?

As presented below - I have couple of sheets from different dates - it will be generated every week I would like to hide old sheets and leave the recent one (I do not want to do it manually)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aovBB.png

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation from `I could not find a function to hide "old" sheets (from previous weeks) and leave just the recent one - any ideas?`. I think that the sheet can be hidded by Sheets API. But I cannot understand the detail of it. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? For example, do you want a sample script for only hiding a sheet using gspread?

Comment: hello, i added a screenshot to my initial question

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your additional information, I cannot still imagine your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I am generating a report - using python & gspread library - through google sheets & google drive API it pastes values in google sheet. Every week a new tab/ worksheet is generated. The problem here is that I would like to hide previous sheets/ tabs and leave just the most recent one.

Comment: Can you try adding `'hidden': True` in the sheet's properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This solution works, with a new update - previous sheet is being hidden:



sh_instance.batch_update(body={
    'requests': [
        {'updateSheetProperties': {
            'properties': {
                'sheetId': sh_instance.get_worksheet(-2).id,
                'hidden': True
            },
            'fields': 'hidden'
        }
        }
    ]
}
)
```

https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html
batch_update(body)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).